# Is there any PHP framework's scaffolding that can generate migration like Ruby on Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, frameworks, yii, scaffolding

In rails, when generating model, migration is created also.
I'm wondering any PHP framework can do it also?

I'm trying Yii framework now, but seems like I need to generate the migration manually first then generate a model. (or even a third step to generate CRUD :-/)

Thanks

Comment: Cause I have too many clients do not accept anything rather than PHP. They don't even know what is RoR. :Crying:

Comment: Then explain to them what rails is and how you'll get everything done much faster :)

Comment: I tried everytime, sometime it is possible, but this time I'm facing a government bureau. 
Believe me, I Love RoR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try fuelphp framework (http://fuelphp.com) which has excellent scaffold function as well as other amazing functions. It used PHP 5.3.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, full migration support and CRUD generation when building the model. Though the project has finished... I will still put some time playing with it. Much appreciated.

Comment: The experience of using FuelPHP is much better than Yii, from the perspective of a Rails developer.

Answer (score 3):

[CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org) has a [migrations plugin](http://cakedc.com/pierre_martin/2010/02/05/cakephp-migrations-plugin-easily-version-and-deploy-whole-applications), as well as bake console which creates a file to generate your current schema and stuff. I think this might be what you need..

Answer (score 2):

I believe the old Yii dbmigrations extension is obsolete in favor of Yii's built-in migration functions available since Yii 1.1.6:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration
However, it does seem like the OP may have tried that already as was not happy with the amount of manual work still involved compared to his experience with RoR.

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine 2 has a [migrations component](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations/2.0/docs/reference/en). It's completely separate from the ORM, so you don't have to be using Doctrine to use this. This is probably the most popular solution right now.

It does require php 5.3 though.